# Protractor finding a popup element in a web UI

Tags: protractor

I'm trying to hover the mouse over a given element so that the help balloon appears. I need help finding the element to take action on.

I'm new with protractor. I have the docs in front of me and I've also reviewed many SO postings regarding protractor and element finding. By and large I'm doing ok, but I have one that's a bit complicated and eluding my newb ability.
I've tried many variations of by.className(), by.css() and either it finds multiple elements, or None. The acp-help-circle appears 6 times in the given UI. I'm only sharing a snippet of the code (for brevity sake of course).

```
<ng-include src="'OtherSettingsTemplate'" class="ng-scope"><div class="nok-content-panel panel panel-default ng-scope ng-isolate-scope" is-collapsed="true">
  <div class="panel-heading ng-scope util-clickable" ng-class="{'util-clickable':contentPanel.collapsable}" ng-click="contentPanel.headerClick($event);">
    <i ng-show="contentPanel.collapsable" class="toggle-icon icon-states acp-caret-bottom" ng-class="{'acp-caret-bottom' : !contentPanel.isCollapsed, 'acp-caret-right': contentPanel.isCollapsed}" style=""></i>

    <b class="ng-binding ng-scope">Other</b>
    <div class="right ng-scope">
      <i class="acp-help-circle ng-scope" popover-placement="left" popover-trigger="'hovertooltip'" uib-popover-html="'Doc Control and Doc Manager cannot be enabled at the same time for the same configuration. Please only enable the feature used within your Licensed Property Manager configuration.'" nok-popover="Doc Control and Doc Manager cannot be enabled at the same time for the same configuration. Please only enable the feature used within your Licensed Property Manager configuration."></i>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="panel-collapse ng-scope in collapse" uib-collapse="contentPanel.isCollapsed" style="" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="content-wrapper">
    <form name="editApp.otherSettingsForm" class="otherSettingsForm ng-pristine ng-valid ng-scope" novalidate="">
      <fieldset>
        <div class="fieldsRow">
          <div class="col-title">
            <span class="label ng-binding">Document Control</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lef">
            <nok-switch-button ng-model="editApp.configuration.otherSettings.dcEnabled" size="medium" is-disabled="editApp.configuration.otherSettings.docManagerEnabled &amp;&amp; !editApp.configuration.otherSettings.dcEnabled" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty"><div class="switch-button medium switch-button-off" ng-click="switchButton.toggleSwitch()" ng-class="{'switch-button-on': switchButton.on,
                'switch-button-off': !switchButton.on,
                disabled: switchButton.isDisabled,
                readonly: switchButton.isReadonly}" style="">
    <div class="switch-button-container">
        <span translate="components.switch-button.onLabel" translate-values="" class="ng-scope">On</span>
        <label>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
        <span translate="components.switch-button.offLabel" translate-values="" class="ng-scope">Off</span>
    </div>
</div>
</nok-switch-button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-right">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldsRow">
          <div class="col-title">
            <span class="label ng-binding">Inky</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lef">
            <nok-switch-button ng-model="editApp.configuration.otherSettings.inkyEnabled" size="medium" class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty"><div class="switch-button medium switch-button-off" ng-click="switchButton.toggleSwitch()" ng-class="{'switch-button-on': switchButton.on,
                'switch-button-off': !switchButton.on,
                disabled: switchButton.isDisabled,
                readonly: switchButton.isReadonly}" style="">
    <div class="switch-button-container">
        <span translate="components.switch-button.onLabel" translate-values="" class="ng-scope">On</span>
        <label>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
        <span translate="components.switch-button.offLabel" translate-values="" class="ng-scope">Off</span>
    </div>
</div>
</nok-switch-button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-right">
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="fieldsRow p-t-10">
          <div class="col-title">
            <span class="label ng-binding">Doc Manager</span>
          </div>
          <div class="col-lef">
            <nok-switch-button ng-model="editApp.configuration.otherSettings.docManagerEnabled" size="medium" is-disabled="editApp.configuration.otherSettings.dcEnabled &amp;&amp; !editApp.configuration.otherSettings.docManagerEnabled " class="ng-pristine ng-untouched ng-valid ng-isolate-scope ng-not-empty"><div class="switch-button medium switch-button-off" ng-click="switchButton.toggleSwitch()" ng-class="{'switch-button-on': switchButton.on,
                'switch-button-off': !switchButton.on,
                disabled: switchButton.isDisabled,
                readonly: switchButton.isReadonly}" style="">
    <div class="switch-button-container">
        <span translate="components.switch-button.onLabel" translate-values="" class="ng-scope">On</span>
        <label>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
            <span></span>
        </label>
        <span translate="components.switch-button.offLabel" translate-values="" class="ng-scope">Off</span>
    </div>
</div>
</nok-switch-button>
          </div>
          <div class="col-right">
          </div>
        </div>
      </fieldset>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</ng-include>
```

Just a few of the many iterations I've tried...

```
element(by.className('acp-help-circle'))  //finds > 1. The class is not unique.
element(by.cssContainingText('Doc Control and Doc Manager cannot be enabled at the same time for the same configuration. Please only enable the feature used within your Licensed Property Manager configuration.'))  //this finds none.
```

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Could you share some of the html surrounding this element? Often surrounding HTML can provide useful identifying information which can be used to help us identify when used with the target element

Comment: @DublinDev, you asked for it! :)  Unfortunately, I can only comment with about 550 characters! I guess I'll update the original post.

Comment: @DublinDev, I updated the posting. Thank you for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your looking for the locator, Try any of the below locator to select help balloon

```
const ele = element(by.css('div.panel-heading>div>i.acp-help-circle'));

const ele = element(by.css('div.right>i.acp-help-circle'));

const ele = element(by.css('div.panel-heading>div>i'));
```

If you still get more than one element. Then try the below one

```
const ele = element.all(by.css('div.panel-heading>div>i.acp-help-circle')).get(1); //Change the index as per the index of your element in the element array.
```

Hope it helps you

Comment: This one works! Thank you so much! element.all(by.css('div.right>i.aci-help-circle')).get(2)

Comment: @MichaelLupo Do mark the answer as correct so that will help others who face the same pblm.